# Spring boot admin 1.5.1 does not display logging managment with spring boot 1.5.2.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

i'm using spring boot admin 1.5.1 along with spring-boot 1.5.2.RELEASE.
everything works fine, expect that the logging managment tab is hidden.

i tried to access my client app(spring-boot 1.5.2) logging api and it works fine.
according to the  [spring-boot-admin document reference](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.5.1/#loglevel-management) i don't need to setup any configurations

those are the tabs i see :
[image]

any idea why i don't see logging tab(logging managment) ??

Comment: is your client also a boot 1.5 app? is it's /logging endpoint active?

Comment: What do you mean in my client? The logging api is active, i wrote it in the question

Comment: Upvoted this question. The Spring Boot Admin project is very poor in documentation and error handling - good questions must be encouraged, not shunned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a defect on spring boot admin 1.5.1
will be fixed in the next milestone 1.5.2

[github issue](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/477)